# presto failed to search data from hive

Tags: apache-spark, hive, presto, trino

I faced a problem that i can not get data from hive, and hive data come from spark.

```
io.prestosql.spi.PrestoException: Cannot get bucket number from path: hdfs://xxx:8020/warehouse/tablespace/managed/hive/ods_mflex_bpm_szgx.db/workflow_requestbase/year=2018/part-00000-74647672-c3b8-4b36-98d3-95734e8bd376.c000.snappy.orc
    at io.prestosql.plugin.hive.BackgroundHiveSplitLoader$HiveSplitLoaderTask.process(BackgroundHiveSplitLoader.java:257)
    at io.prestosql.plugin.hive.util.ResumableTasks$1.run(ResumableTasks.java:38)
    at io.prestosql.$gen.Presto_344____20201118_122905_2.run(Unknown Source)
    at io.airlift.concurrent.BoundedExecutor.drainQueue(BoundedExecutor.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get bucket number from path: hdfs://xxxx:8020/warehouse/tablespace/managed/hive/ods_mflex_bpm_szgx.db/workflow_requestbase/year=2018/part-00000-74647672-c3b8-4b36-98d3-95734e8bd376.c000.snappy.orc
    at io.prestosql.plugin.hive.BackgroundHiveSplitLoader.lambda$getRequiredBucketNumber$9(BackgroundHiveSplitLoader.java:733)
    at java.base/java.util.OptionalInt.orElseThrow(OptionalInt.java:271)
    at io.prestosql.plugin.hive.BackgroundHiveSplitLoader.getRequiredBucketNumber(BackgroundHiveSplitLoader.java:733)
    at io.prestosql.plugin.hive.BackgroundHiveSplitLoader.loadPartition(BackgroundHiveSplitLoader.java:511)
    at io.prestosql.plugin.hive.BackgroundHiveSplitLoader.loadSplits(BackgroundHiveSplitLoader.java:321)
    at io.prestosql.plugin.hive.BackgroundHiveSplitLoader$HiveSplitLoaderTask.process(BackgroundHiveSplitLoader.java:250)
    ... 6 more
```

somebody who know the reason?

Comment: I suppose your table definition has bucketed (clustered) property, but the data doesn't. You can change table definition.

Answer (score 1):

The table is declared as bucketed in Hive metastore but the actual files are not bucketed. You need to fix the table declaration to make it non-bucketed. I think you need to use Hive CLI for that.

Note that even if Spark populated the table bucketing the files, it would lead to incorrect query results due to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19256. We're going to detect this and prevent incorrect query results in https://github.com/trinodb/trino/pull/6012